# Как реализовать чтение файла подобного содержания?

Tags: c#

Всем привет, скажите, как сделать, чтобы программа читала такого вида файл, и главное, чтобы значения после **=**, чтобы его, к примеру, можно было передать в переменную или вообще как-нибудь работать с этими данными?

```
#SERVER
IP=127.0.0.1
PORT=4101

#MYSQL
SQL_HOST=localhost
SQL_DBASE=test
SQL_USER=test
SQL_PASSWORD=159357

#GAMESERVER
GS_IP=127.0.0.1
GS_PORT=4110
GS_CHANNELS=1
GS_TYPE=1

#LOGIN SERVER OPTIONS
AUTO_ACCOUNT_CREATION=TRUE
```

**Файл settings.cfg, надо подобное сделать**

Comment: обчно подобную информацию хранят в XML-подобном файле

Comment: а данного вида файл приидется только парсить "руками"

Comment: обычно подобную информацию не хранят в XML, можно конечно, но он же хранит настройки программы, а не предназначен для передачи. Если не ошибаюсь, это старая традиция виндовс приложений хранить конфиги в .cfg файлах

Comment: @wind ну если заменить #SOME на [SOME], то это будет вполне себе .ini-файл, а в сети куча материала (+готовый код) о том, как с этим форматом работать.

Comment: Да но **как** это делать? Мне не нужен XML

Comment: читай строчку посимвольно, если встречаешь знак "=" - после него начинай считывать значение, если пробел или конец строки - заканчивай, переходи к следующим..

Comment: Так вот мне надо узнать КАК это сделать....

Comment: @VioLet, от того, что вы скачаете чужие наработки в данной области ничего не меняется - ето парсинг руками (пусть и чужими). Разве что импортить функции из kernel32 и работать через них - других способов я не знаю.

Comment: @Spectre - XML от лукавого, вообще идиотский формат, такое ощущение что придумали его за ночь, но зато стандартизировали, это да

Comment: @Spectre, с чего бы такое агрессивное отношение к хмл? ) Вполне вменяемый формат...

Answer (score 3):

Могу предложить сделать так, с помощью регулярных выражений и linq

```
const string pattern = "(?<Key>.+)=(?<Value>.+)";
            var matches = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText("congig.cfg"), pattern);
            Dictionary<string,string> settings = matches.Cast<Match>().
                ToDictionary(match => match.Groups["Key"].Value, match => match.Groups["Value"].Value);
```

Comment: Вот этот вариант норм и вообще парсинг текста без регулярок для меня не может быть красивым, хотя всякие ситуации конечно бывают...

Comment: Сам начинающий программист, и регулярные выражения подучил недавно...Сейчас даже не представляю как раньше без них мог обходиться.

Answer (score 2):

Что-то вроде подобного (требует доработки):

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

using (TextReader textreader = new StreamReader("config.txt")) {
    string row;

    while ((row = textreader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        if (row[0] == "#") {
             // Пропускаем комментарий
             continue;
        }

        string[] options = row.Split('=');

        dictionary.Add(options[0], options[1]);                    
    }
}
```

Comment: красиво =)

Comment: row = row.Trim();
    if (row.Length == 0 || row.StartsWith("#")) {
       ...

Answer (score 1):

Ничего сложного:

1. открываете файл,
2. читаете по строчке,
3. парсите.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$new = array();
$array = file('test.txt');
foreach($array as $v){
    if(preg_match_all('/(.*)=(.*)/ism', $v, $match))
    $new[trim($match[1][0])] = trim($match[2][0]);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new);
```

Comment: В вопросе же четко указан язык...

Comment: Извиняюсь, просмотрел.